# Sequential version of the Eberlein-Shmul'yan theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, alternative-proof, weak-convergence

**Theorem**: A Banach space is $(i)$ reflexive iff $(ii)$ every bounded sequence possesses a weakly convergent subsequence;
see e.g. Thm 3.18 and 3.19 in Brezis' 2010 book.

The implication $(i) \implies (ii)$ is essentially due to the Hahn-Banach Theorems.

Can $(ii) \implies (i)$ be shown without the use of [Banach-Alaoglu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach-Alaoglu_theorem) and the [Eberlein-Shmul'yan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem) theorems, and by a more direct proof (i.e. one that possibly avoids topological compactness, for it is not mentioned in the statement of the theorem)?

**References**. H. Brezis, *Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations*, Springer-Verlag (2010)

Comment: There is an [elementary proof](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0172&DMDID=dmdlog27&LOGID=log27&PHYSID=phys128#navi) Eberlein-Shmulyan but it is still quite long.

Comment: Indeed, I was hoping for something more direct.